# Set of coefficients of degree three monic real polynomial with three real roots is connected.

Tags: polynomials, connectedness, cubics, path-connected, roots-of-cubics

Let $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ be a cubic polynomial with real coefficients $a, b, c,$ and define:

$$D=\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid \text{the polynomial}\ p(x)\ \text{factors into linear factors over }\ \mathbb{R^3}\}.$$
Then:

(a) $D$ is connected (as a subset of the topological space $\mathbb{R}^3$).

(b) For any $(a,b,c)\in D$, we have $a^2\geq 3b$.

This was a true/false question in one of my test (NBHM 2023). I have found some [conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350910/roots-of-a-polynomial-of-degree-3) but those were seems to be quite overwhelming. Can someone please give me some hint? My guess is it may be the case that $D$ is path connected.

Comment: write three real roots as p,q,r and then for different point in D, choose a linear path for each root($p_1 \to p_2$ and so on. For the second question its a collary of AG inequality using root expression.